# a script of mine doesnt work(on collision enter)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

OnCollisionEnter does not work
here is the script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Collision : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void OnCollisionEnter(UnityEngine.Collision other)
    {
        if(other.gameObject.tag == "Wrong")
        {
           print("test");
        }
    }
}
```

both of their BoxColliders "isTrigger" is set to false(the player is a capsule does it matter?)
the player has a rigidbody with "isKinematic" set to True(the player is using Character Controller as the movement does it matter?)
idk what to do the platform is 3D help plz

Comment: A) id try calling it something other than Collision. B) does player have a rigid body C) check it calls and its not falling on the id by putting a debug statement in

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your collision isn't firing because none of them have a non-kinematic rigidbody attatched. Try checking all the constraints to replicate `Is Kinematic` in the rigidbody. I tested it in Unity and it works.
[Rigidbody constraints image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UcT39.png)